# How to sort by descending date within a conversation in MS Outlook 365

Tags: office-365, sorting, outlook-365

I am using MS Outlook and I would like to sort emails based on conversation and then descending by date within each conversation so that the most recent email is at the TOP vs bottom.

I tried Arrange By > Sort > conversation index (ascending) + received (descending) and it still sorts by ascending date within each conversation. I’ve tried selecting that setting and restarting, I’ve tried switching back and forth between received (descending) and received (ascending) and in all cases the new stuff sorts to the bottom within each conversation for some reason.

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue with 365. When I untick the option "Use Classic Indented View" in my Conversation Settings they are shown most recent first.